# Appium can not find elements in Android after device popup or activity

Tags: appium, android-alertdialog, ui-automation, appium-android

I am using Appium 1.8.1 to automate my Android application.

When there is any device alert appears Appium stops finding element after i click on ok button for that popup.

Currently i run the code to relaunch the application after any popup appears  and it works after that but i need proper solution for this because relaunching the application is not the solution as per my understanding.

Comment: Just a workaround, you do not have to relaunch the app. You can instead put the app to background and then bring it to foreground and it will work. I'm also having the same problem. This work around works for me.

Comment: Thanks Vighnesh, i could not put it in the words properly but its not relaunch i am doing the same driver.runAppInBackground(2); and thats the work around but i need some solution from appium team.

Comment: Yes. Totally agree. There is a bug already on github page. Expecting fix from appium team

Answer (score 0):

In Python:

```
driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[0])
```